# Is there a guarantee that nonzero/nontrivial vector space will have a subspace that is not the zero vector space or itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know that the trivial vector space and the vector space itself are subspaces of any vector space. But, what I do not understand is that, given that the vector space is nonzero, how do we know that there is a subspace that is not the trivial vector space or itself?

Comment: If you got this wrong, show us your answer, so we can tell you why your answer was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *don't* know that. If you see $\Bbb R$ as a real vector space, then its only vector subspaces are $\Bbb R$ and $\{0\}$. This works over any field.

More generally, if $V$ is a vector space over some field $k$, then the assertion “there is a subspace of $V$ that is not the trivial vector space or $V$ itself” is equivalent to the assertion that $\dim V>1$.